# Drag, Drop & Rendering in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am making a flutter project and one module requires drag drop & rendering features.

Image:-
[Basic idea built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DE7i.jpg)

Working:-

1. The outline will be selected.
2. Features should be dragged and dropped on to the outline

I am confused where to get started with. Is this even possible in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Draggable widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html